# I want to display different images OnMouseOver and OnMouseOut

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a JS function for highlighting Text in blue on mouseOver and where I am passing two parameters - id, action in my . I have written 2 simple css for mouseover to blue and mouseout to black.
I want to add code to display different images to onmouseover and onmouseout events.
The thing is - I have two different images in one location which displays accordingly when you mouseover and mouseout. 
e.g. Onmouseover - image1........ Onmouseout- image2.
I want to make it generic.

CSS:

```
.AttachOnMouseOverText{
    color: blue;        
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.AttachOnMouseOutText{
    color: black;       
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;     
}
```

JavaScript :

```
function highlightBG(id,action,img) {   
    if(action==0)
    {
        document.getElementById(id).className='AttachOnMouseOverText';
    document.getElementById(img).src='#ContactsImagePath#'+ img+'_over.gif';            
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(id).className='AttachOnMouseOutText';           
    document.getElementById(img).src='#ContactsImagePath#'+ img+'.gif';             

    }
}
```

HTML :

```
<td align="center" class="AttachOnMouseOutText" id="folderid" nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" onClick="go('addfolder');" onMouseOver=" highlightBG('folderid',0, 'icon_folder');this.style.cursor='hand'; return true;" onMouseOut="highlightBG('folderid',1, 'icon_folder'); return true;">
<p class="Margin"><img name="icon_folder" id="icon_folder" src="#ContactsImagePath#icon_folder.gif" alt="Add Folder" align="middle" border="0" ></p>
<span>Add Folder</span>
```

If you check I have added third parameter 'img' and making it generic by passing it in document.getElementById. #ContactsImagePath# is location where images are stored. 
i have written _over.gif because all the images have this format. e.g. on mouseover "image_over.gif" will be called. hence i have written this.
But my problem is when the image name will change in that location, then my function would crash. any idea how to do it?

Comment: If you check I have added third parameter 'img' and making it generic by passing it in document.getElementById. #ContactsImagePath# is location where images are stored. 
i have written _over.gif because all the images have this format. e.g. on mouseover "image_over.gif" will be called. hence i have written this.
But my problem is when the image name will change in that location, then my function would crash. any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

use css instead

```
.image_container{
         background:url('image1.jpg');
}


.image_container:hover{
         background:url('image2.jpg');
}
```

Comment: But I have 10 such images in my Form. So how to make it generic in one css? the different images are stored in one location - #ContactsImagePath#. I am using ColdFusion technology.

Comment: well you have to define a logic here,for 10 images you have to write 10 css style declaration.adding all images to a sprite would be a optimized solution.

give all 10 elements some data-image-id , on mouseover through attr().or data() extract that data-image-id value and add it as a class and remove the same on mouseout.

Css will take care of image swap,js will be generic here.

Answer (score 1):

try this one this is the simplest

```
<img src="Images/search-btn.gif" onmouseover="this.src='Images/search-btn-over.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='Images/search-btn.gif'" />
```

Comment: You are correct Sumit. But requirement is image should also be changed when you mouseover on the Text also. hence i put all my events inside <td>

Answer (score 0):

Give background property in your CSS classes

```
.AttachOnMouseOverText{
  color: blue;        
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: url('image_mouseover.gif');
}

.AttachOnMouseOutText{
  color: black;       
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;  
  background: url('image_mouseout.gif'); 
}
```

Comment: Yes. but this will work for only one image. I have several images under different <td>'s in one Form.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hover on the div tag to change the image.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #container {
            position: absolute;
            width: 50%;
            height: 20%;              
        }
        img {
            width: 50%;
            height: 100%;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            left: 25%;
        }
        #right {
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);                
        }
        #container:hover #info {
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }
        #container:hover #right {
            transform: rotateY(360deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <img id="right" src="right.png" alt="icons" />
        <img id="info" src="info.png" alt="icons" />
    </div>
</body>
```